# Duplicate & identify certain rows in a Pandas Dataframe - regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I did'nt find any solution about my issue.

I want to identify & duplicate with regex certains rows of my DataFrame.

For example my df :

```
   var1  
0  House A and B 
1  2 garage + garden 
2  fridges
```

The result that i want in var2 (keep my var1 too) :

```
   var1                  var2
0  House A and B         House A
1  House A and B         House B
2  2 garage + garden     Garage 1
3  2 garage + garden     Garage 2
4  2 garage + garden     Garden
5  fridges               fridge 1
6  fridges               fridge 2
```

I don't know exactly how to do that, I think with regex it's a good idea, but i'm not sur.
I tried with str.contains but the results was not good.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The expected output is what appears in var2 or do you want a combination of var1 and var2 in a new column?

Comment: @powerPixie the expected output is what appears in var 2 in a second column, but keep the var2 too.

Comment: @Emma, when words are in plural in my case, it's for 2 items

Answer (score 1):

If those three cases are exhaustive, then you may use my solution, my solution uses a combination of regex matching and split.

```
#the hard part
def my_scan(t):
    #Split
    #only '+' and 'and' are considered
    cond = re.findall(r'(.+)(and|\+)(.+)' , t)
    if len(cond):
        t = [_.strip() for _ in cond[0]]
    else:
        t = [t]

    #Process
    #Case 1 'House': and
    if 'and' in t:
        t.remove('and')
        #add 'House' to the second element
        t[1] = re.split(' ', t[0])[0]+' '+t[1]

    #Case 2 'Garage + Garden': + with numeral
    elif '+' in t:
        t.remove('+')
        x = []
        ##check for numerals in front
        for _ in t:
            if (re.match(r'^\d+', _)):
                temp = _[(re.match(r'^\d+', _)).end()+1:] #'garage'
                #append by the number of numeral times
                for i in range(int(re.match(r'^\d+', _)[0])):
                    x.append(temp+' '+str(i+1))
            else:
                x.append(_)
        t = x

    #Case 3 'Fridges': single word that ends with an s
    else:
        if (re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]+s$', t[0])):
            t = t[0][:-1]
            t = [t+' 1', t+' 2']

        else:
            t[0] = t[0]+' 1'

    return t

#the easier part
def get_df(t):
    output1 = []
    output2 = []
    for _ in t:
        dummy = my_scan(_)
        for i in range(len(dummy)):
            output1.append(_)
            output2.append(dummy[i])


    df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':output1,'var2':output2})
    return df


#test it
data = {'var1':['House A and B','2 Garage + Garden', 'Fridges']}
df = get_df(data['var1'])
print(df)

#bonus test
data1 = {'var1':['House AZ and PL','5 Garage + 3 Garden', 'Fridge']}
df = get_df(data1['var1'])
print(df)
```

Printed df output from your original data, `data = {'var1':['House A and B','2 Garage + Garden', 'Fridges']}`.

```
                var1      var2
0      House A and B   House A
1      House A and B   House B
2  2 Garage + Garden  Garage 1
3  2 Garage + Garden  Garage 2
4  2 Garage + Garden    Garden
5            Fridges  Fridge 1
6            Fridges  Fridge 2
```

Printed df output from an additional test data, `data1 = {'var1':['House AZ and PL','5 Garage + 3 Garden', 'Fridge']}`.

```
                   var1      var2
0       House AZ and PL  House AZ
1       House AZ and PL  House PL
2   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garage 1
3   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garage 2
4   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garage 3
5   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garage 4
6   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garage 5
7   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garden 1
8   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garden 2
9   5 Garage + 3 Garden  Garden 3
10               Fridge  Fridge 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, regular expression wouldn't be the best idea to do this task, yet you can write some expressions to split them, how-to-code-it or how to find the plural words (which you'd probably want some NLP library for it) would be some other different stories:

```
([A-Za-z]+?)\s([A-Z])(?=\s+and|$)|([0-9]+)?\s+([A-Za-z]*?)(?=\s+\+|$)
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8Gysno/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8Gysno/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---